# Eclipse Plug-In Installation Issues

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, checkstyle, subversive

I'm beginning to work with Eclipse for some Java development. I'm quite new to Eclipse, as I am a Visual Studio developer normally.

I tried to install the CheckStyle Eclipse Plug-In and Subversive, using the Eclipse "Install new Software" feature. No errors, everything seems to have worked well. Clicking on "What software is already installed?" in the Install-dialogue shows me a list of installed plug-ins. Both Subversive and CheckStyle for Eclipse are listed.

My only problem is that neither of them "work", that means I cannot see any new UI elements. According to the manual I have, I should see a new node "CheckStyle" in a project's properties. I haven't. I don't know exactly what Subversive looks like, but I'm sure there's a way to conveniently perform check-out operations etc.

Manually copying the downloaded plug-in to the dropins-folder and restarting Eclipse subsequently does not help either. Is there a way to reliably find out whether there occurred any errors - I have no error message at all, what drives me crazy and makes the problem pretty difficult to describe/Google...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My only problem is that neither of them "work", that means I cannot see any new UI elements.

There is a simple reason. I have saved my Eclipse installation in Windows' Program File folder. Thus **I need to run it as an administrator under Windows 7**, otherwise the plug-ins cannot be copied to their directory - but unfortunately no error message appears and they are listed under installed plug-ins.

Answer (score 3):

Click **Help->About.**
Click on **Plug-in details**. You can see all the loaded plugins.
Check whether checkstyle plugin is there.
If not , go to **Window->Show View - > Error LOg**.
You can see all the error logs including your checkstyle loading errors.

Before doing all the above things don't forget to **restart eclipse** after installing the plugins.
Or exit from the eclipse ,go to eclipse folder and execute bellow command in command prompt
**eclipse.exe -clear**

It is very easy to install and use eclipse plug-ins. Once you started using eclipse you will agree this :)

Comment: Thank you, this error log is pretty useful - for other things too. I set up a new installation of Eclipse, worked much quicker that finding the error. Basically it is very easy to install plug-ins, as long as thinks work well... :)

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak for checkstyle; but for subversion there will be no views added to the UI by default. Try going to Window->Show View->Other. There will likely be an "SVN" section under other; I think you'll want the one called "SVN Repositories". It will likely open in the bottom panel of the Java profile. Right click in it and you can add repositories. After checking out projects you use the Team menu to manage your project (right click on the project in the Project view)

Checkstyle probably put something under Window->Preferences; may need to mess around in there.

Answer (score 0):

You could check for Subversive at Window -> Show View -> Other -> [type "svn"].

For CheckStyle: Window -> Preferences -> [type "check"]